# mp.Image() call with sliced numpy array raises TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, mediapipe

I try to use Mediapipe for detecting hands.

The code

```py
cv_mat = cv2.imread("hand.jpg")
cv_mat = cv_mat[..., ::-1]
image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=cv_mat)
```

does not work with error:

```
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=cv_mat)
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint8])
    2. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint16])
    3. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float32])

Invoked with: kwargs: image_format=<ImageFormat.SRGB: 1>, data=array([[[255, 255, 255],...
```

if I remove the second line `cv_mat = cv_mat[..., ::-1]`  - it works.

Why?

Does the slice has another type?
It works fine in opencv I can change it, wfite to a file etc...

Comment: `[:, :, ::-1]` I'm guessing you want to convert to BGR?

Comment: Yesfrom BGR to RGB for Mediapipe, and it works fine with cv2.cvtColor() instead of slice.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for the [mp.Image constructor](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/api/solutions/python/mp/Image) could be a little clearer but it only supports "C order" inputs:

> Pixels are encoded row-major in an interleaved fashion. [...] Image can be created by copying the data from a numpy ndarray that stores the pixel data continuously

[Poking around the construction helpers](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/6cdc6443b6a7ed662744e2a2ce2d58d9c83e6d6f/mediapipe/python/pybind/image_frame_util.h#L38) confirms that it's assuming the C order.

Using `[...,::-1]` to convert to RGB changes the stride associated with the matrix, so it's effectively no longer contiguous (although the underlying data still is, in some sense).

Easy fix is to make a copy of the data (e.g. `cv_mat[..., ::-1].copy()`), or just use `cvtColor()` as you mentioned, which has minimal overhead but is explicit about what you're doing :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this is useful or not...or actually relate to the problem being discussed here, But I had similar error and somehow I found a solution. but I really don't understand neither the spec of Open CV nor Media Pipe yet, so I can't explain why. Maybe it's just my things (environment, version inconsistency, my misunderstanding).

This is the code I got from official document for mp.Image class.

```
cv_mat = cv2.imread("whateva.jpg")
image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=cv_mat)
```

https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/api/solutions/python/mp/Image

Of course I expected that the code will work...because it came from the document, right? But this happened.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/home/video dev/mp test/mp_test_02.py", line 86, in <module>
    image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=cv_mat)
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint8])
    2. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.uint16])
    3. mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.image.Image(image_format: mediapipe::ImageFormat_Format, data: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float32])

Invoked with: kwargs: image_format=<ImageFormat.SRGB: 1>, data=array([[[16, 19,  0],
        [12, 19,  3],
        [12, 19,  1],
        ...,
        [11, 18,  2],
        [14, 16,  2],
        [14, 18,  3]],
        ...,
        [29, 81, 81],
        [26, 83, 82],
        [29, 79, 91]]], dtype=uint8)
```

So I randomly try a couple of things. This worked.

```
image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=np.asarray(cv_mat))
```

So I confirmed cv_mat is actually numpy.array. And I got this...

```
type(cv_mat)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(np.asarray(cv_mat))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
cv_mat.shape
(1280, 853, 3)
np.asarray(cv_mat).shape
(1280, 853, 3)
```

I think, return value of cv2.imread is already numpy array, whose type is dtype=uint8...I confirmed it, too. So what's the difference here? np.asarray reallocated memory or something and it worked??

It worked for some reason but it didn't make me happy because I have no idea why it worked. Do you think is that numpy things that I don't know?

I'm working on Windows 10, with portable python Ver 3.10.2. Version of media pipe is 0.10.0. numpy version is '1.24.3', by the way. I installed all packages with pip.